# @XmlElement on a collection of attributes only element doesn't print xsi:nil

Tags: jaxb, jaxb2, xml-nil

I have a very curious situation.

```java
public class Child {

    @XmlAttribute
    public String name;
}
```

```java
@XmlRootElement
public class Parent {

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        final Parent parent = new Parent();
        parent.children = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            final Child child = new Child();
            child.name = Integer.toString(i);
            parent.children.add(child);
        }
        final JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Parent.class);
        final Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
        marshaller.marshal(parent, System.out);
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "child", nillable = true)
    public List<Child> children;
}
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<parent>
    <child name="0"/> <!-- xsi:nil expected -->
    <child name="1"/>
    <child name="2"/>
</parent>
```

Question 1: Why there is no `xsi:nil` attribute on those `children`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xsi:nil` will only be written for items in the cle film that are `null`.  In your example all the items in the `List` are instances of `Child`.

**Parent**

If you update code in your `Parent` class to add a null into the `children` `List`.

```java
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        final Parent parent = new Parent();
        parent.children = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            final Child child = new Child();
            child.name = Integer.toString(i);
            parent.children.add(child);
        }

        // UPDATE - Add a null entry to the List
        parent.children.add(null);

        final JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Parent.class);
        final Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
        marshaller.marshal(parent, System.out);
    }
```

**Output**

The `child` element corresponding to the `null` entry will contain the `xsi:nil` attribute.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<parent>
    <child name="0"/>
    <child name="1"/>
    <child name="2"/>
    <child xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
</parent>
```